# NodeJS Create an array of functions and execute it through async.series

Tags: node.js, async.js

Starting my learning curve on NodeJS, I am trying to call a sequence of functions using async.series. Each function is a command line that is called remotely using REST.

```
function TestStorageDeviceBasic()
{
    scenario = [
        'cmdline1',
        'cmdline2'
    ];

    tasks = [];
    scenario.forEach(command => { tasks.push(RunCommand(sessionId,command));});
    async.series(tasks);
}

function RunCommand(sessionId, cmdLine)
{
    var options = {
        uri: `http://${domain}/api/v1/commands`,
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            'session-id' : `${sessionId}`,
            'command-line': `${cmdLine}` 
        }
      };

      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            log.debug(`\"${cmdLine}\" status code successful`)
            log.debug(body);
        }
        else
            log.error(`\"${cmdLine}\" status code failed`,error);
      });
}
```

I am getting a few problems even though the RunCommand function seems to be called.

```
(node:21008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expected a function
    at wrapAsync (C:\work\MyJavascriptProject\my_sample\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:198:50)
    at C:\work\MyJavascriptProject\my_sample\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:2952:13
```

Why RunCommand is not considered a function?

Comment: You are *calling* `RunCommand` and pushing the result of the function into tasks. The result of `RunCommand` is not a function. You might try using `.bind()` to make a function with the captured parameters.

Comment: Just a comment about using async third parties: better use async await (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things you need to modify in the code

- Wrap the RunCommand in a function and then push it in tasks array
- Make sure you pass callback while wrapping up
- Modify the `RunCommand` to have a callback as well so that `async.series` can use the output from the callbacks.

Since you are not passing callback for your RunCommand, it is only getting executed once as `async.series` doesn't know when to proceed ahead. The modified code would look like

```
function TestStorageDeviceBasic() {
  scenario = ["cmdline1", "cmdline2"];

  tasks = [];
  scenario.forEach(command => {
    tasks.push(callack => RunCommand(sessionId, command, callack));
  });
  async.series(tasks, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
  });
}

function RunCommand(sessionId, cmdLine, callack) {
  var options = {
    uri: `http://${domain}/api/v1/commands`,
    method: "POST",
    json: {
      "session-id": `${sessionId}`,
      "command-line": `${cmdLine}`
    }
  };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      log.debug(`\"${cmdLine}\" status code successful`);
      log.debug(body);
      callack(null, body);
    } else {
      log.error(`\"${cmdLine}\" status code failed`, error);
      callack(error, null);
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx. So when doing that, i get "Error: Callback was already called" with the stack trace. This where I am stuck for the last hour.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? it is working fine for me. see this - https://repl.it/repls/PrevailingAshamedUtilities It is not exactly same but enough to give you an idea

Comment: could it because the next line was using `err` instead of `error`? I have updated the code. Also worth checking if `log.error` line is not giving any error.

Comment: I had a silly error in my code such that the braces was missing and the callback was always code. Perfect, thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're *calling* `RunCommand` and then pushing its return value into `tasks`. Instead, push a function that makes the call:

```
scenario.forEach(command => { 
    tasks.push(() => RunCommand(sessionId,command));
});
```

Comment: Actually it did solve the problem, but only the first function is being called after calling async.series(tasks)

Comment: @isaac.hazan - see my answer, that has explanation of why you are seeing that behavior. Hope that helps.